# Windows Vista updates

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I am sick and tired unchecking update to IE8 every few days when new update is pushed. How do I permanently set update as not wanted for some items? IE8 and Office 2007 in particular.

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Comment: should go on superuser :)

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the update and "Hide Update".

(You can later unhide it if you wish.)